# Unable to write the extracted data from the XML into a text file

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I am working the natural language processing , where I need to extract the data between the AbstractText tags of the XML. I am able to extract the data from the XML but when I am trying to write the text into a text file. Only the text from the last tag is going(written) into the text file.
Below is my code:

```
h1=et.parse("C:\\Users\\harsh\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\DataSets\\zika.xml")
h3=h1.getroot()
h2=h1.findall('PubmedArticle')
for child in h2:
for node in child.getiterator():
    if node.tag=="AbstractText":
        h3=node.text
        print(h3)  
file=open("C:\\Users\\harsh\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\DataSets\\Extracted.txt","w")
        file.write(h3)
        file.close()
```

Let me know where I am going wrong. Printing h3 is showing me data from all tags. But I am unable to write it. Point me to write direction.

Comment: You might want to try opening the file with `a` instead of `w` -- using just `w` will delete the current file every time it loops through the nodes, [per the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). So it probably only captures the last h3 value...

Comment: file=open("C:\\Users\\harsh\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\DataSets\\Extracted.txt","a") is also writing only the data from the last tag.

Comment: @HarshaVardhan It's hard to tell from your formatting, but it looks like you're opening the file only after the loop, in which case the mode doesn't matter.

Comment: @AmiTavory, I am still unable to resolve this issue. Any directions?

Comment: @HarshaVardhan Sorry, I really don't. Good luck.